# Undefined property: stdClass::$account_id error in my code

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have encountered the following error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$account_id (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\awsconfig\app\views\search.blade.php)

here is the code which is causing this error :

```
$resource_types = array();
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::Instance'] = 'EC2Instance';
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface'] = 'EC2NetworkInterface';
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::VPC'] = 'VPC';
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::Volume'] = 'Volume';
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'] = 'EC2SecurityGroup';
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::Subnet'] = 'Subnet';
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::RouteTable'] = 'RouteTable';
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::EIP'] = 'EIP';
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'] = 'NetworkAcl';
$resource_types['AWS::EC2::InternetGateway'] = 'InternetGateway';


 $accounts = DB::table('aws_account')->get();
 $account_list = array();




foreach(glob('../app/views/*.json') as $filename)
{
    //echo $filename;
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);

    if($data!=null)

    {


            $decoded=json_decode($data,true);  


            if(isset($decoded["Message"])) 
            { 
            //echo "found message<br>";
                $message= json_decode($decoded["Message"]);
if(isset($message->configurationItem))
{
//  echo"found cfi<br>";    
            $insert_array = array();
                $cfi = $message->configurationItem;
                switch ($cfi->configurationItemStatus)
                {

                    case "ResourceDiscovered":
                //echo"found Resource Discovered<br>";  
                        if (array_key_exists($cfi->resourceType,$resource_types))

                        {
                            //var_dump($cfi->resourceType);
                            $resource = new $resource_types[$cfi->resourceType];

                            foreach ($cfi->configuration as $key => $value)
                            {
                                if (in_array($key,$resource->fields))
                                {
                                    $insert_array[from_camel_case($key)] = $value;
                                }
                            }




                            $resource->populate($insert_array);
                            if (!$resource->checkExists())
                            {
                                $resource->save();

                                    if(isset($cfi->configuration->tags))
                                    {
                                       foreach ($cfi->configuration->tags as $t )

                                        {

                                        $tag= new Tag;
                                    $tag->resource_type = "instance";

                                    $tag->resource_id = $resource->id;
                                    $tag->key = $t->key;
                                    $tag->value = $t->value;

                                    $tag->save();


                                        if(isset($cfi->awsAccountId))
                                    {
                                     foreach ($accounts as $a)

                                     {
                                       $account_list[] = $a->account_id;
                                     }


                                    if (!in_array($account_id,$account_list))
                                    {



                                    $account_id = new Account;
                                    $account_id->aws_account_id = $cfi->awsAccountId;

                                    $account_list[] = $account_id;
                                     $account_id->save();

                                        }        






                                }
                                }
}




                            }

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            echo "Creating ".$cfi["resourceType"]." not yet supported<br>";
                        }





                    break;
```

I know it will be something silly I appreciate all help as always thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on your code this is a simple demonstartion i am explanning, `DB::select` will returns a array which contains several objects (may be more than one), and then you assign it to`$this->food`.

Remember, the `$this->food` looks like

`Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [name] => 'Beef'
    )
)`

Actually, $this->food->name is trying to access a undefined property.

Solution 1:

You should use `$this->food[0]->name` to access it.

Thought it looks weird, but it works.

Solution 2:

Why not call `Food::find($id)` to fetch the object instead of `$food = new food($id)`

You can learn more by reading this `http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent`

Hope this might help you in solving your problem